# Debugger Hangs in Google Doc Function

Tags: debugging, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

I'm trying to debug a function in some app script for my Google spreadsheet.  When I choose my function (called Calc) from the drop down and hit the Bug icon to step through it, all I get is a message at the top of the IDE saying "Preparing for execution...".  Is there something else I'm supposed to do?

[image]

> BTW - I thought of posting this on the google forums but I noticed that all the support team for app script seem to weigh in here.  Hope this is the right place!

Answer (score 1):

Line 13 is wrong. See the order in for loop. Will never stop as is.

Comment: True that the order of c++ and  c<=lastCol should be inverted. However, in his version, the loop should finish even earlier, because the first value or 8 is immediately increased. Why should Google Apps script be hanging with the message "preparing for execution", as if it were an infinite loop, the execution would be long, not the preparation.

Comment: I know its been awhile but I thought I'd hop on to help clarify somethin for you @vinnief. What you're saying is not correct because of your interpretation as to how for loops are processed. The middle statement is a boolean evaluation, meaning, it is checking if the expression in there is true or false. So, yes, the value is increased to 8, but the third statement is not a boolean expression, so it doesn't evaluate anything. ++c will always evaluate to true because any number that is not 0 evaluates to true. This is infinite loop because the condition to stop is ++c. c<=lastRow isn't used

Answer (score 1):

Your loops are not setup correctly.

They must be:

```
Line 13 for (c=8; c <= lastCol; c++)
Line 16 for (r=4; r <= lastRow; r++)
```

Comment: don't you mean c++ and r++?